# How to set timout for request on REST Assured?

Tags: java, rest-assured

Im sending post request with REST Assured. the problem is that it has no timeout at all.
In my case the server is getting out of reach sometimes and this locks the request forever.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found an answer. i'm posting it here, hopefully it will help someone.

```
RestAssured.config=RestAssuredConfig.config().httpClient(HttpClientConfig.httpClientConfig().
        setParam("http.connection.timeout",300000).
        setParam("http.socket.timeout",300000).
        setParam("http.connection-manager.timeout",300000));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can see [here](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#http-client-config). It has several ways to do it, check this:

```
when().async().with().timeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
```

or

```
given().config(config().asyncConfig(withTimeout(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))).
```

Comment: getting errors can not resolve methods asyncConfig & withTimeout

Answer (score -1):

Rest-Assured is based on apache httpclient:

```
RestAssured.config = RestAssured.config().httpClient(httpClientConfig()
.setParam(ClientPNames.CONN_MANAGER_TIMEOUT, Long.valueOf(DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_IN_MS))  // HttpConnectionManager connection return time
.setParam(CoreConnectionPNames.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_IN_MS) // Remote host connection time
.setParam(CoreConnectionPNames.SO_TIMEOUT, DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_IN_MS)  // Remote host response time
```

);